# Java-8 - sort keys of Map

Tags: java-8, hashmap

I have this Java Map:

```
 Map<ScheduleAbsenceHeaderHistoryTypeEnum, ValueObject>
 ....
 public enum ScheduleAbsenceHeaderHistoryTypeEnum {

     ADDITIONAL_HOURS("ADDITIONAL_HOURS"),
     HOLIDAY("HOLIDAY"),
     REMAINING_HOLIDAY_HOURS("REMAINING_HOLIDAY_HOURS"),
     REMAINING_HOLIDAY_DAYS("REMAINING_HOLIDAY_DAYS"),
     TRANSFER_HOLIDAY("TRANSFER_HOLIDAY"),
     INCREMENT_HOLIDAY("INCREMENT_HOLIDAY"),
     ..
```

and I will sort the keys of the map alphabetically.
Is there a possibility to do this in a simple way?

Comment: Why do you pass that redundant name string to the `enum`’s constructor? The name can be retrieved via `name()` without that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a map sorted by the enum’s name like

```
Map<ScheduleAbsenceHeaderHistoryTypeEnum, ValueObject> map
    = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(Enum::name));
```

This uses the constant name as declared in the enum class, e.g.

```
enum ScheduleAbsenceHeaderHistoryTypeEnum {
    ADDITIONAL_HOURS, HOLIDAY, REMAINING_HOLIDAY_HOURS,
    REMAINING_HOLIDAY_DAYS, TRANSFER_HOLIDAY, INCREMENT_HOLIDAY,
}
```

There is no need to specify that name manually.

But if you have a property that might be different from the name, you may use

```
Map<ScheduleAbsenceHeaderHistoryTypeEnum, ValueObject> map
  =new TreeMap<>(Comparator.comparing(ScheduleAbsenceHeaderHistoryTypeEnum::getProperty));
```

to sort by that specific property.

Answer (score 1):

Given `Map<ScheduleAbsenceHeaderHistoryTypeEnum, ValueObject> map`:

```
    map.keySet().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ScheduleAbsenceHeaderHistoryTypeEnum::getName))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

will produce a sorted `List<ScheduleAbsenceHeaderHistoryTypeEnum>`.

**Edit:**

If you like to get a `Map` which has its keys sorted while you put elements into it use something like this:

```
SortedMap<ScheduleAbsenceHeaderHistoryTypeEnum, ValueObject> map =
    new TreeMap<ScheduleAbsenceHeaderHistoryTypeEnum, ValueObject>(comparing(ScheduleAbsenceHeaderHistoryTypeEnum::getName)) {{
        put(HOLIDAY, null);
        put(REMAINING_HOLIDAY_DAYS, null);
        put(TRANSFER_HOLIDAY, null);
        put(INCREMENT_HOLIDAY, null);
        put(ADDITIONAL_HOURS, null);
    }};
```

The statement:

```
map.keySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

will produce the following output:

```
ADDITIONAL_HOURS
HOLIDAY
INCREMENT_HOLIDAY
REMAINING_HOLIDAY_DAYS
TRANSFER_HOLIDAY
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to still keep the Map?